# Photoshop makes Wacom tablet touch lag and non responsive

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stylus

**Case:**
I just found out my wacom touch (not pen) stops working when i open photoshop and it works totally fine in windows when photoshop is closed but it stops exactly when photoshop loads.

i did the "# Use WinTab and PSuserconfig" already and pen problems are gone. all i need is to fix touch.

(also when photoshop is running in minimized for example under chrome the touch works and stops randomly)

i have latest wacom driver and photoshop cc 2019.
checked the previous version of wacom driver and didn't work.

Comment: In the Wacom Tablet Properties program, do you have anything set for Photoshop in the Application section?

Comment: well it worked a bit and now its the same idk why i think i have to turn the touch off for using photoshop and since it works realy well when photoshop is closed im kinda sure its not hardware related :/

Comment: status update i used wacom diag window while using photoshop and the input was alright in diag while cursor was unresponsive. im going to install the Photoshop2017 and check if the problem persists. will update

Comment: i should be I. You need to make some effort with your question

Answer (score 0):

The Electrical Interference from laptop body caused the problem since i use a very small portable desk the tablet was like super close to laptop body. nearly touching the body.

I'm guessing execution of Photoshop elevated this situation because of the usage of dedicated graphic which is off before hand and an increase in total voltage usage of laptop thus increasing the range of interference, because a centimeter of movement to left or right would change the function of touch.

well i'm happy its fixed and its not hardware related i hope this answer helps people.